# ReplaceRepeated made a single replacement where I expected multiple replacements to be made

Tags: pattern-matching

This seems like a very simple action:

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f} //. {r___, x_, y___} :> {r, 1, y}
```

but it replaces only the first element giving

> ```
> {1, b, c, d, e, f}
> ```

Why? what am i doing wrong? The specified pattern seems to describe every element of the list..

Clarification. I want to change all elements of the given list to 1 using `ReplaceRepeated` only. For a list of symbols it is straightforward:

```
 {a, b, c, d, e, f} //. {r___, x_Symbol, y___} :> {r, 1, y}
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

But what if the list has elements of different type?

And another tweak on this problem. What if i want to modify list elements using only patterns such as:

```
 someFun[n_?EvenQ] := n + 1;
          someFun[n_?OddQ] := 2*n;
          Replace[{1, 2, 3}, {r___, x_, y___} :> {r, someFun[x], y}]
```

> ```
> {2,2,3}
> ```

I could do it using

```
 Map[someFun,{1,2,3}]
```

> ```
> {2,3,6}
> ```

but still would like to do it using pattern. Is it possible?

Comment: Default behavior is longest match....

Comment: I understand. Is it possible to use only patterns to force list iteration and subsequent substitution?

Comment: Add to your OP what it is you're trying to accomplish - iteration with your pattern (or fixedpoint with it) would give same results...

Comment: `{a,  b,  c,  d,  e,  f}  //.  {r___,  Except[1],  y___}  ->  {r,  1,  y}` produces `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern matches `<nothing><a><bcdef>` so the a is replaced with 1. 
Next pass, the pattern matches `<nothing><1><bcdef>`, since replacement would result in no change, replacement stops.

It's not clear from the OP in its current state what it is you want to accomplish. Add that info, and you'll surely get responses.

It seems you *might* be after

```
ReplaceList[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {r___, x_, y___} :> {r, 1, y}]
```

giving

```
{{1, b, c, d, e, f}, {a, 1, c, d, e, f}, {a, b, 1, d, e, f}, {a, b, c,
   1, e, f}, {a, b, c, d, 1, f}, {a, b, c, d, e, 1}}
```

but again, your OP needs to be clarified.

Per your update, if all you want is all elements replace by 1, no need for `ReplaceRepeated`, just use something like

```
lst={a,b,c,d,e,f}
Replace[lst, _ -> 1, 1]
```

Or even faster for big lists

```
ConstantArray[1,Length@lst]
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the [BlankNullSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) defaults to matching zero arguments, if possible. Try this:

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f} //. {x__, y___} :> {y, 1}
```

> {1,1,1,1,1,1}

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for such straightforward replacement, but when i try to do modification such as:    {1, 2, 3} //. {x__, y___} :> {y, someFun[x]}   the evaluation runs into an infinite loop. Why?

Comment: Because at some point zentient's solution stops changing the list (when it becomes a list of 1s, further application of his rule does not alter anything), while repeated application of `somefun` as in OP will indefinitely increase the values of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your more general question of how to apply an arbitrary function using your replacement scheme, you can do it like this:

```
f[x_] := x^2 + 1
First /@ 
  (Range[6] //. {r___, x : Except[tagged[___]], y___} -> {r, tagged[f[x]], y})
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37}
> ```

But that's rather silly, isn't it? It's just doing `Map` in a very obscure and much slower way.

```
f /@ Range[6]
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37}
> ```